# Unable to set the value of a dropdown using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using an @Html.DropDownListFor. I have no issues populating the drop down but I am unable to set the selected value using JQuery. Here is the simplified version of the code.

```
@{
var listItems = new List<ListItem>
    {
            new ListItem { Text = "Select Question", Value = "Select Question" },
new ListItem { Text = "test", Value = "test" }
}


<div class="row">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecurityQuestion, new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
<div class="row">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SecurityQuestion, new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "security", @class = "securityALLQuestion" })
</div>
<div class="row">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecurityQuestion1, new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
<div class="row">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SecurityQuestion1, new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"), new {id="security1", @class="security" })
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript function to set it. I take all the values from the #security dropdown, and then use it to set #security1 dropdown.

```
$('.security').on('change', function () {
    var values = [];
    var optionValues = [];

    $('#security option').each(function () {
        values.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        optionValues[i] = "<option value=\"" + values[i] + "\">" + values[i] + "</option>";
    }

var temp ='test'
$('#' + 'security1').html('').html(optionValues);
$('#' + 'security1').val(temp);
})
```

The values of values[] and optionValues[] are as expected.

On checking the console I am getting the value of temp but the alert for the entire statement is null. Am I missing something?

Possible Issue: Is it because I am only setting the value and not the text for the question?

Comment: Do you have errors in console ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai No errors on console.

Comment: Please try this: `$('#security1').val(temp)`.

Comment: Does not change anything. There is some issue in which I am referencing that control.

Comment: I think i got the problem you have: change `new {id="security1"}` to this `new {@id="security1"}`. You missing `@` symbol before `id`.Another solution(without another `id`) is to use directly `$('#SecurityQuestion1').val(temp)`.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Does not make any difference with the @. I have added additional code which might help you identify the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132228/discussion-between-alexandru-ionut-mihai-and-the-outsider).

Answer (score 0):

There's two things required for this to work:

1. You have a valid jQuery reference to the select element
2. The value you're trying to set *exactly* matches one of the contained option elements' value attribute.

First, ensure that you're properly selecting the select element. Use `console.log` to output the value of `$('#' + security1)` to your browser's developer console. Also, ensure that the JavaScript variable, `security1`, both exists and holds the appropriate id you're expecting.

Once you're sure that the jQuery element reference is good, look at the options in the generated HTML of the page (view source). Check the value of `temp` (perhaps log it to the console to be sure) and compare it to the value attributes on those options. It must match *exactly*, or it will not cause an option to be marked as selected.

Comment: I did check both of your concerns and they match exactly as required. I have added extra piece of code if it can help you identify the issue.

Comment: You're clearing the select innerHTML, but never adding back any options (`values` is an empty list). Therefore, it can't set the value to "test" because there are in fact no options with that value; there are no options period.

Comment: values.push($(this).attr('value')); is used to set the value. I am getting the values in the dropdown list. It is only the selected value which is blank which is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this will solve

```
$("#custom_address_to").get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
```

if you want to select the 1st element in the drop down